# MySQL query: Update user table plan field if payment table status = verified for the same user

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have database tables:

#### user

> id       username    plan
>
> 1       ahmad

Note: plan is a enumeration containing either `'a', 'b', 'c' or ''`.

#### payment

> id       status         username
>
> 1      verified           ahmad

Now I want to write a query like

> Update user table plan field if payment table status = verified for the same user.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Update user table plan field to what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update user, payment set plan = 'value' where status = 'verified' and user.username = payment.username
```

Is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you drop the username column in the payment table and replace it with a userid column. It's much more efficient for MySQL to look up based on a numeric ID than a string. Also, it simplifies things if you ever have to change a username.

With that said, here's how I would do it:

`UPDATE user, payment SET user.plan="a" WHERE User.id = payment.userid AND payment.status="verified"`